# Element Click Intercepted Error in Night watch JS

Tags: click, element, nightwatch.js

ElementClickInterceptedError Occurred when i tried to intercept a button click in chrome browser.
The page contains a search button and a create button, The search button is intercepting properly and the element button is correctly identified, but on clicking its showing the error.

> ``
>
>  create state
>
> `

```
>it('createStateformloadtest',function(browser){
> browser
>             .url(process.env.BASE_URL + 'states')                              
>             .waitForElementVisible('#state-create-button', 5000) 
>             .click('#state-create-button')
```

```js
An error occurred while running .click() command on <#state-create-button>: element click intercepted: Element <div class="add-btn-container" id="state-create-button">...</div> is not clickable at point (77, 148). Other element would receive the click: <input class="form-control form-control-sidebar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="sidebar-search-input">

Tried removing the search button and different .click forms with Id , name and class.Also tried giving co ordinates.
how to identify the actions taking place on click function and test it.
```

Comment: Clicks try to be the centre of the element. Perhaps you've still got it over there.